Android: can one disable ContextMenu-handling on Short-Click?
Android triggers a view's context menu on both, a short click as well as a long click. Can one somehow disable the former?
I have a view for which I want to define both, a (Short-)ClickListener AND a ContextMenuListener, but the latter should ONLY be triggered, when the user does a long-click on the view. By default Anroid triggers the context menu's creation and display in both cases. However, I want to use the short-click for something different. Can one teach the system to leave a View's short-click alone (or rather: trigger the View's ClickListener in that case instead of the ContextMenu)?
